# What are some good investment options for a foreigner in France who doesn't have a permanent residence permit or a French citizenship?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies, france

I'm a non EU citizen living in France, with a work permit valid until December 2021. I don't have permanent residence permit yet, but will apply for it soon with a year or two. So I was wondering what are some good investment options (e.g. mutual funds etc. and others) in France that I can invest in now? I'd like to invest small, say 1000-1500€ at one time, or invest 100€ every month. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Invest in an ETF that holds U.S. bonds, notes, or bills at short durations and that gets the investor both in-the-dollar and hopefully gets the three-month U.S. Treasury interest rate.

The reason for this sector selection is a current theme of slowing global growth but with Europe leading the concerns more-so than the U.S.

Then the reason not to go with longer durations is the worry of a large supply of U.S. Treasury securities coming to market. However, longer durations would ordinarily perform well in slowing economies. Avoid high-yield bonds at durations of more than six-months when economies are slowing. Concentrate on A-rated bonds.

Or put the investment in an over-the-counter Forex account that is based in Euros and hold an unleveraged dollar position as a sell-side EUR/USD currency pair. That gets the investor both in-the-dollar and gets about a 1.75% to 2% interest rate after commissions.

Also, gold is showing current strength.

Comment: @S Spring: Thank you for your answer; I'm not a US or Canadian citizen (I've an Indian passport)-would this suggestion be equally applicable for me?

Comment: Yeah, you are earning income in Euros and you might want to  hedge the Euro while  also finding an interest rate.